# Running tasks on dynamically collected EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm trying to write a role with tasks that filters out several EC2 instances, adds them to the inventory and then stops a PHP service on them.

This is how far I've gotten, the add_host idea I'm copying from here: http://docs.catalystcloud.io/tutorials/ansible-create-x-servers-using-in-memory-inventory.html

My service task does not appear to be running on the target instances but instead on the host specified in the playbook which runs this role.

```
---
- name: Collect ec2 data
 connection: local
 ec2_remote_facts:
     region: "us-east-1"
     filters:
       "tag:Name": MY_TAG
 register: ec2_info
- name: "Add the ec2 hosts to a group"
  add_host: 
    name: "{{ item.id }}"
    groups: foobar
    ansible_user: root
  with_items: "{{ ec2_info.instances }}"

- name: Stop the service
  hosts: foobar
  become: yes
  gather_facts: false
  service: name=yii-queue@1 state=stopped enabled=yes
```

UPDATE: when I try baptistemm's suggestion, I get this:

```
PLAY [MAIN_HOST_NAME] ***************************

TASK [ec2-manage : Collect ec2 data] 
*******************************************

ok: [MAIN_HOST_NAME]

TASK [ec2-manage : Add the hosts to a new group] 
*******************************************************

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************

MAIN_HOST_NAME                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

UPDATE #2 - yes, the ec2_remote_tags filter does return instances (using the real tag value not the fake one I put in this post).  Also, I have seen ec2_instance_facts but I ran into some issues with that (boto3 required although I have a workaround there, still I'm trying to fix the current issue first).

Comment: OK, updated with the latest output based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play tasks on a group of targets you need to define a new play after you created the in-memory list of targets with `add_host` (as mentionned in your link). So to do that you need like this:

```
   … # omit the code before

   - name: "Add the ec2 hosts to a group"
     add_host:
       name: "{{ item.id }}"
       groups: foobar
       ansible_user: root
     with_items: "{{ ec2_info.instances }}"

- hosts: foobar
  gather_facts: false
  become: yes
  tasks:

   - name: Stop the service
     hosts: foobar
     service: name=yii-queue@1 state=stopped enabled=yes
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work for me, the "Stop the service" task doesn't run for me.

Comment: You are sure `ec2_remote_facts` returns any ec2 instances (try with a task `debug` after on `ec2_info.instances` ).  by the way  `ec2_remote_facts` was replaced by `ec2_instance_facts`. Reply in the original question, please